# How to reference JSON.NET in SSIS

Tags: ssis, json.net

I need to parse some JSON in an SSIS package.  JSON.NET seems popular and well supported.  I downloaded the latest version, but...

My development machine already has **97** different copies of Newtonsoft.Json.dll in various places.  The target deployment server has over **120**.  Installing yet another one isn't going to help matters.

I'm using VS 15.9 for development.  I read that JSON.NET is already built-in to VS [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/using-newtonsoft-json-in-a-visual-studio-extension/), but I sure can't find it anywhere in "Add reference".  *using* in C# doesn't seem to bring up anything.

- How do I get started?
- How will the reference translate when I deploy?  Do the .DLL paths need to be the same on dev machine/server, or can it work off some kind of signature?

EDIT:
I've got started, and it works beautifully.  I referenced this file:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Extensions\Common\Newtonsoft.Json.dll.

It exists on both my target servers.  But is this best practice?  I have no idea on how best to reference DLLs from SSIS.